# Ошибка при использовании модифицированной CollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Есть экран(CollectionViewController):[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также у меня есть класс, где есть настройки для ячейки.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я привязал этот класс к ячейке, ячейке присвоил identifier = "cell". И когда я пытаюсь указать Xcode, что у этой ячейки есть ImageBoard, выходит ошибка при работе программы.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Без `.. as! CellPhoto` все отлично работает, но мне необходимо работать с ячейкой. Буду очень благодарен, если подскажите где я ошибся.

P.S.
На сколько я понял, из за восклицательного знака выходит ошибка, т.к. ячейка Cell равна nil!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S.S

Вопрос решен, нужно было удалить полностью метод register! Спасибо за помощь :)

Comment: Лучше добавлять код текстом а не картинкой

Comment: На последнем скриншоте не видно полного описания ошибки

Comment: Если вы используете сториборд для ячейки зачем вы ее регистрируете?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотри дебагером, перед тем как происходит краш, не nil ли у тебя cell, а также его Outlets.

Cкорее всего ты неправильно подключил Outlet и он у тебя nil (я про imageBoard)

Так же проверьте указали вы ваш кастомный класс у ячейки в storyboard и указан ли верно в storyboard у ячуйки reuseIdentifier.

Хочу напомнить, что если вы создаете ячейку напрямую в storyboard, то вы не должны писать collectionView.register....... Система делает все за вас. Попробуйте удалить это.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я переподключал, все равно не работает. Создавал пустые проекты, и делал там, тоже ошибка вылетает. Вылетает из-за nil значения, если я беру cell.label?.text = "1", то из за ? все работает, но нет результата.

Comment: @LoonyMan обновил ответ

Comment: На сколько я понял, у меня почему то считает что ячейка Cell не существует. Я вернул обратно в методе register, перепроверил все названия подключенных классов к объектам и reuseidentifier. Обновил вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае ошибка происходит потому что `cell` который вы получаете от `collectionView` - обычный `UICollectionViewCell` а вы кастите его как `CellPhoto`.

Это происходит из-за того что вы зарегистрировали обычный `UICollectionViewCell` для `reuseIdentifier`

Чтобы это исправить зарегистрируйте `CellPhoto.self` в методе `register(_ cellClass: AnyClass?, forCellWithReuseIdentifier identifier: String)`

Comment: Вот так? self.collectionView!.register(CellPhoto.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

Comment: Да, в таком случае вы зарегистрируете CellPhoto и вы сможете получать его при использовании reuseIdentifier

Comment: Теперь ошибка возникает при любом взаимодействии с элементами в этой ячейки, обновил вопрос